# What does a pre-addressed priority mail return envelope mean?

Tags: driving-license, postal-system

If I try to re-new my nys drivers license it says on this site
[How to renew a license - New York DMV](https://dmv.ny.gov/driver-license/how-renew-license)

> the renewal notice we mailed you (MV-2) or if you don't have it, use
> the Application for Permit, Driver License, or Non-driver ID (PDF)
> (MV-44) a Vision Test Report (PDF) (MV-619) completed by an eye care
> professional  a check or money order payable to ‘Commissioner of Motor
> Vehicles’

**> > a pre-addressed priority mail return envelope with your application.**

> This will help ensure that we send your license to the correct
> address

Does this mean I just need to only include an envelope with my international address where I want the renewed license sent or must I include postage as well? Does the price of renewal cover the international postage? As it is, I do not know where to get postage overseas that would be accepted in the U.S. postal service.

Comment: Have you asked NY DMV? DMV's Contacts page https://dmv.ny.gov/contact-us/contact-us contains options to ask questions by email or by telephone.